# Rerooting dolls; needle keeps breaking?

Tags: tool-selection, tool-modification

I created a homemade rerooting tool as found on google somewhere. It's an exacto knife with the blade removed, filled with some cork and a needle stuck in with the sharp end. I cut the eye of the needle to form an irregular V shape. I let the needle stick out so that I have room to push through the holes in the head.

My problem is the needle keeps breaking. I need quite a small needle to make sure the cut eye fits in the holes in the head, but the smaller the needle the thinner the needle. Some of the smaller holes require more pressure, causing the needle to break. I went through a full pack of needles already and I need some help.

Is there a way to keep my needle from breaking?
Would wrapping it with something like ductape, paper, fabric or anything give it some extra strength?

I can add a picture later if I am able to buy some more needles.
I made a sketch for now:

This is what I had for the current length
[image]

And I think the next one should be a little shorter:
[image]

Comment: Can we see a picture of the tool you made? How much of the needle sticks out and how much is _supported_ inside the tool? Has using multiple needles damaged the cork inside allowing the needle to move more?

Comment: @Matt I have added an illustration until I am able to take a picture. I replace the cork inside (they have to be bits of cork instead of one solid piece because I am not able to solidly slide one whole piece in) after every needle breaks to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a long, somewhat flexible needle for basting beads. I think it's less likely to break.